# Getting rid of section header

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using Scientific Workplace 4.1 and want headers for each section of a book. I put the following in the preamble:

```
\thispagestyle{headings}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\rightmark
```

That works, but it also puts "Contents" as a heading for the Table of Contents, which is generated automatically since I put Make TOC in the Front matter. I do not want "Contents" as a heading for the 3 or so pages at the beginning where the TOC appears. I know about the command `\thispagestyle{plain}`, but it is not clear where I would put that. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: You need to show us exactly how your setup of this book is. A normal book, written with the book class sets the toc header using chapter*, so anything section does not apply.

Comment: BTW good luck next time you get a new computer, the company that made swp went under after 40(?) years, so you cannot install it on a new computer.

Comment: I didn't use book class-I am not familiar with that, but maybe I'll look into it. I simply put Make Toc in the Front Matter.